# Unable to get response from HttpURLConnection POST method

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I've seen multiple threads for this issue but unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to solve my problem from them.
Need help to find out how to fix my Java code, as you can guess my coding skills are still limited.

Managed to find solutions for "GET" & "DELETE" methods.
There is a sample written in C# & CURL but my skills are limited to interpret parts of the code.

https://github.com/tradeio/api-csharpclient/blob/master/Tradeio.Client/TradeioApi.cs

Here is my Java implementation:

```
    public String PlaceOrder(String symbol, String side, String type, String quantity, String price) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        LinkedHashMap<String, String> form = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        form.put("Symbol", symbol);
        form.put("Side", side);
        form.put("Type", type);
        form.put("Quantity", quantity);
        form.put("Price", price);
        form.put("ts", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        return signAndSend2("/order", form, "POST");
    }

        private String signAndSend2(String url, LinkedHashMap<String, String> payload, String method)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        String nonce = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String baseUrl = UrlTradeio.urlV1;
        String sign = "";

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(payload);
        String formForPayload = json + "";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Entry<String, String> param : payload.entrySet()) {
            if (sb.length() != 0)
                sb.append('&');
            sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            sb.append('=');
            sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));

        }

        byte[] postDataBytes = sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        int postDataLength = postDataBytes.length;

//      System.out.println(sb);
//      System.out.println(formForPayload);

        sign = hmac512Digest(formForPayload, TRADEIO_SECRET_KEY).toUpperCase();
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(baseUrl + url).openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Sign", sign);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Key", TRADEIO_API_KEY);
        conn.setRequestProperty("ts", nonce);
        conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
        conn.setRequestMethod(method);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
        conn.connect();

        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
            sb.append((char)c);
        String responseBody = output.toString();

        return responseBody;

    }
```

Depending on what I try I have several error messages.

````
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://api.exchange.trade.io/api/v1/order
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1913)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
    at Private.TradeioApi.signAndSend2(TradeioApi.java:223)
    at Private.TradeioApi.PlaceOrder(TradeioApi.java:113)
    at test.main.main(main.java:37)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solved the issue. Removed this:

```
conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
```

And send the request like this:

```
try(OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
            os.write(postDataBytes);
        }
```

Comment: Based on your answer, it probably was an issue, because most output and input streams internally buffer bytes, and using reading the input before its fully closed may cause certain bytes not to be send to the other server